# ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi

Tags: python, django

Ive got my django apps running in Django 1.3 within Python 2.4 and no virtual environments.
I have a new project that runs python 2.7 and django 1.5. I can place this new project within a virtual environment. However Ive now recompiled Apache to use Python2.7 for WSGI but now my Python2.4 apps dont work.

Is there an easy way around this other then completely upgrading python2.4 to 2.7 across the board and then having each django version inside a virtual environment ?

Thanks,

Comment: wsgi lib don't exist with some python version , mod_python only works with some version but that mod_python is not longer maintain.

Comment: There shouldn't be any backwards compatibility issues from Python 2.4 to 2.7. Can you be more specific about what breaks?